# Reactjs hiding and displaying start screen by using hooks instead of classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I have some code that displays a start screen but when I press the start button it gives me an error: "this.props.clickevent" is not a function. How can I re remove the start screen once the start button is pressed by using hooks rather than classes? 
 I basically need to make the gameOn variable true in Homescreen so it sets the screen to hidden but not sure how to do this with hooks.

Here is the code I have been fidelling with for the home screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import './homescreen.css';
var isGameOn = false;
class Homescreen extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
}
  clickMe(){
//call parent function that manages state
 this.props.clickEvent();

   }
         render(){
       return (
          <div className={isGameOn ? "homescreen homescreen--visible" : "homescreen homescreen--hidden"}>
        <div className="homescreen__box">
          <h1 className="homescreen__title">Space&nbsp;  Matcher</h1>
          <div className="homescreen__stats">
            Games Played: <strong className="homescreen__number" >{this.props.gamesWon}</strong>
          </div>
          <button className="homescreen__shuffle-button " onClick={this.clickMe} >Start!</button>
           </div>
          </div>
         )
     }
}

export default Homescreen;
export {isGameOn}
```

And here is part of the App which renders my home screen:

```
import Homescreen, {isGameOn} from './homescreen'
var gamesPlayed = 0;
export default function App() {

function startGame(){
    gamesPlayed+=1;
    isGameOn = true;
    console.log(isGameOn);
  }
  return (

    <Homescreen gameOver = {isGameOn} gamesWon = {gamesPlayed} clickEvent = {startGame}/>
 }
```

Here is the css:

```
.homescreen{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  z-index: 4;
}

.homescreen--visible{
 animation-name: pop-in;
 animation-duration: .75s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.homescreen--hidden{
  //display: none;
 animation-name: pop-away;
 animation-duration: .75s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.homescreen__box{
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,51,0,1) 0%,rgba(153,0,0,1) 100%);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30em;
  border: 6px solid orange;
}

.homescreen__title{
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  font-size: 8vw;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  color: orange;
  line-height: 8vw;
}

.homescreen__stats{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}

.homescreen__number{
  color: #ffcc00;
}

.homescreen__shuffle-button{
  font-size: 5vw;
  border-radius: 10em;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: orange;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,51,0,1)         0%,rgba(153,0,0,1) 100%);
  //width: 50%;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all .25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  padding-left: 7vw;
  padding-right: 7vw;

  &:hover{
background: #990000;
letter-spacing: .1em;
//box-shadow: 0px 0px 5vw #ffcc00;
border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the css (homescreen.css) in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.clickEvent(this.props.clickEvent);
```

Code where above must equal with gameOn function in App component.

if gameOn function doesnt have a parameter you need to change it like this;

```
  clickMe(){
//call parent function that manages state
      this.props.clickEvent();
  }
```

Your App component must be like below;

```
import React, { Component  } from 'react';

    export default class App extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.isGameOver = false;
            this.gamePlayed = 0;
        }

        gameOn(){
            this.isGameOver = !this.isGameOver;
            this.gamePlayed +=1;

        }
        render(){
            return(
                <Homescreen gameOver = {this.isGameOver} gamesWon = {this.gamesPlayed} clickEvent = {gameOn}/>

            )
        }

}
```

Comment: What would the function look like in App. I don't understand how to do this part in App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a gameOn function and maybe update the state of your App.

```
var gamesPlayed = 0;
export default function App() {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gameStarted: false
    };
  }
  gameOn(){
    this.setState({gameStarted: true})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Homescreen clickEvent = { this.gameOn.bind(this) }/>
    )
  }
}
```

Now you can conditionally show and hide stuff in render based on state.gameStarted.

Note: You also need to bind this to the function so that this can be used in the callback see here (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: is it possible to do this in App by using hooks rather than states

Answer (score 0):

There is some parts in the question which are not clear, but i suppose that you want to hide the content after clicking the button 'Start'.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isGameOn: false,
      gamesPlayed: 0
    };
  }


  startGame = () => {
    this.setState({
      isGameOn: true,
      gamesPlayed: this.state.gamesPlayed + 1
    })
    console.log(this.state.isGameOn);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Homescreen isGameOn = {this.state.isGameOn} gamesWon={this.state.gamesPlayed} clickEvent = {this.startGame}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Homescreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './homescreen.css';
class Homescreen extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
    }
    clickMe(){
      //call parent function that manages state
      this.props.clickEvent();

    }
    render(){
      return (
        <div className={!this.props.isGameOn ? "homescreen homescreen--visible" : "homescreen homescreen--hidden"}>
          <div className="homescreen__box">
            <h1 className="homescreen__title">Space&nbsp;  Matcher</h1>
            <div className="homescreen__stats">
              Games Played: <strong className="homescreen__number" >{this.props.gamesWon}</strong>
            </div>
            <button className="homescreen__shuffle-button " onClick={this.clickMe} >Start!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default Homescreen;
```

here is a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tnfbkz?file=Homescreen.js)

Comment: Is it possible to omit the states in App and use hooks instead?